# AS3 - XML Playlist with Single-Track Looping

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5.5

So this one has me stumped. My plan for my website is to have music tracks pulled from an XML file which act as the background music for the various .swfs loaded by the menu buttons. I.e. hit 'Home', and it takes you back to the home .swf and plays the appropriate music. I want to do this through XML rather than attaching the music directly to the .swf to cut down on load time (syncing isn't a concern), as I can't seem to retain audio quality without bulking up the .swf significantly.

I'm encountering two problems: one is that with the current code, the music only plays once, and doesn't loop. The other is that I want the functionality to play one song as an intro, and then continue to loop another. I.e., hit the home button, intro plays, followed by the looping section, and never returns to the intro unless you hit home again. I can't seem to figure out how to manage either of these things short of creating a unique function for every single button.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var my_songs:XMLList;
var my_total:Number;

var my_sound:Sound;
var my_channel:SoundChannel;

var current_song:Number;

var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("playlist.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void {
    var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

    my_songs = myXML.SONG;
    my_total = my_songs.length();

    //playSong(0);

    myXMLLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
    myXMLLoader = null;

}

function playSong(mySong:Number):void {
    var myURL = my_songs[mySong].@URL;

    if (my_channel) {
        my_channel.stop();
        my_channel.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playSong);
    }

    my_sound = new Sound();
    my_sound.load(new URLRequest(myURL));
    my_channel = my_sound.play();
    my_channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playSong);
}

test_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlay);
function onPlay(e:MouseEvent):void {
        playSong(0);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

```
   YourSongstarting(0,999); // how ever you call to play the song
```

This above will repeat song forever. I suggest you stream the audio file as this will load the song quicker, then you can keep the songs in memory.you can still use xml or any other external textfile for the audio tracks locations or directly in flash/class files if this site is concrete.

any events you wold like to control simply compare the "Buffer" value out of 100%.Look up streaming audio as3 there are plenty of tutorials with source code if need be let me know i can give you an example.

Comment: Thanks Parele! I did a bit of research and I believe I've set up streaming by claiming a SoundLoaderContext variable at the beginning of the script and then changing "my_sound.load(newURLRequest(myURL));" to "my_sound.load(newURLRequest(myURL), context);" - at least that appears to be all that's needed but I'll have to test it for certain later on.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really clear on what I ought to do with the line you provided. I'm guessing I want to define a new function like that? I'm just not sure where it should be placed or what exactly it accomplishes. Sorry for the newb question, your help so far has been great! =X

Answer (score 0):

You were close

```
var my_songs:XMLList;
var my_total:Number;

var my_sound:Sound;
var my_channel:SoundChannel;

var current_song:Number;

var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("playlist.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void {
    var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

    my_songs = myXML.SONG;
    my_total = my_songs.length();

    playSong(0);

    myXMLLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
    myXMLLoader = null;

}

function playSong(e:Event):void {
    if( current_song > my_total )
       current_song = 0;

    var myURL = my_songs[current_song++].@URL;

    if (my_channel) {
        my_channel.stop();
        my_channel.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playSong);
    }

    my_sound = new Sound();
    my_sound.load(new URLRequest(myURL));
    my_channel = my_sound.play();
    my_channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playSong);
}

test_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlay);
function onPlay(e:MouseEvent):void {
        playSong(e);
}
```